# SwiftUI detect when the user takes a screenshot or screen recording

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

On `UIViewController` we can easy add observer to controller. Like:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didTakeScreenshot(notification:)), name: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func didTakeScreenshot(notification: Notification) {
        print("Screen Shot Taken")
    }
}
```

Or capturing record with:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
    return true
}
```

But how to do it with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isRecordingScreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification)) { _ in
                print("Screenshot taken")
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                isRecordingScreen.toggle()
                print(isRecordingScreen ? "Started recording screen" : "Stopped recording screen")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to tell if user is actually starting or stopping recording in this code example, since the user can start recording and then open the app. But still very useful for detecting screenshot captures.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you probably want [`EnvironmentValues.isSceneCaptured`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/isscenecaptured#)

iOS 17 and forward