# Unable to detect screenshot in simulator

Tags: swiftui, screenshot, wkwebview

I am trying to implement a screenshot and screen recording detection of a web view. After reading the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954077/swiftui-detect-when-the-user-takes-a-screenshot-or-screen-recording) question, I've written the following code:

```
struct WebContentView: View {

    @Binding var htmlName: String
    @State var isRecordingScreen = false

    var body: some View {
        Webview(htmlFileName: htmlName)
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification)) { _ in
                print("Screenshot taken")
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                isRecordingScreen.toggle()
                print(isRecordingScreen ? "Started recording screen" : "Stopped recording screen")
            
            }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the app using the simulator and take a screenshot, nothing is being printed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How you are taking screen shot ?

Comment: @RajaKishan By pressing the "Save screen" icon in the simulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Work fine with Xcode 12.5.1 and seems like you are taking screenshot direct from the save screen button. The save screen button is not a screenshot button.

Take a screenshot from this command

Device -> Trigger Screenshot

[image]